# Medical premiums vs. ACA premiums on tax return

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, health-insurance

I'm currently doing my tax return. In 2017, I paid 12 months of health insurance premiums out of pocket, on my own private plan bought through the Marketplace. In the tax return, it instructs NOT to put these premiums in the Medical Expenses Deduction section if they are from an Affordable Care Act plan.

[image]

You put them in later when it asks for Form 1095-A info. So I did this. But it had no effect on my return. I got no Premium Tax Credit advance during the year (all 12 months of this are $0.00 on form 1095-A). **What's going on? Why did it instruct me NOT to enter my premiums in that previous section, but then also not give me any adjustment for entering them in the next section?**

Edits from comments:
1. I'm single, income is well within the ~11,000 - 47,000 window
2. I'm not eligible for Medicaid in my state
3. The IRS "wizard" for the Premium Tax Credit says I'm eligible

Comment: To add: I got $0.00 in advance Premium Tax Credit, *I'm eligible for it*, but Turbo Tax says 0.00 was the correct amount of the credit? That can't be.

Comment: Single, and my total income for the year was $23,000. I'm not sure how to turn that into the modified adjusted one

Comment: @HartCO Looks like my MAGI would be around 21,000 because of student loan interest. Either way, well inside the eligibility for the Premium Tax Credit.

Comment: Just trying to confirm you qualify since that seems the most likely reason. Does your employer offer coverage that you opted not to take? Parents can claim you still? Hard to root out, sadly.

Comment: @HartCO No employer offered coverage in 2017, and I'm 29.

Comment: Are you eligible for Medicaid? If you are, I believe you aren't eligible for the Premium Tax Credit.

Comment: @CraigW Nope. Healthy single men are not eligible for Medicaid in NC. I don't even have to worry about an income threshold.

Comment: Part 3, column C is not populated on your 1095-A, is it?

Comment: @HartCO All zeros. I got zero advance credit.

Comment: Probably just have to contact Turbo Tax support, could be an errant check-box somewhere or maybe they have an issue on their end.

Comment: @WakeDemons3: "Nope. Healthy single men are not eligible for Medicaid in NC. I don't even have to worry about an income threshold." Low income people in every state are eligible for Medicaid.

Comment: @user102008 You can check yourself. The only 4 categories of Medicaid eligibility in NC are 1. Aged or Disabled. 2. Infants and Children. 3. Families with Dependent Children. 4. Pregnant Women. There's no pure "low income" category where a single man might be eligible.

Comment: @WakeDemons3: Hmm, it seems you are right because NC is one of the states that hasn't expanded Medicaid under the ACA.